# SQL - Get fall back values if no data is available

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, where-clause, fallback

I got a table TBL_A like:

```
   CLASS_ID  PERIOD_DT   MAX_DT
  -----------------------------------
   358614  2018-09-30  2018-09-30
   358614  2017-09-30  2018-09-30
   358614  2016-09-30  2018-09-30
   358614  2015-09-30  2018-09-30
   358614  2014-09-30  2018-09-30
   358614  2013-09-30  2018-09-30
```

and TBL_B LIKE:

```
    CLASS_ID  CLASS_DT   
   ----------------------
    358614  2018-09-30  
    358614  2017-09-30  
    358614  2016-09-30
```

I'm trying to get the result set with CLASS_DT for the past six years and some classes doesn't have enough information. If dates are not available, I need to use previous available data that is close to the current period date. so my final result should look like

**Expected Result**:

```
 PERIOD_DT   FALLBACK_CLASS_DT
-------------------------------
 2018-09-30  2018-09-30 
 2017-09-30  2017-09-30
 2016-09-30  2016-09-30  
 2015-09-30  2016-09-30 // fallback dates, since they are not available
 2014-09-30  2016-09-30
 2013-09-30  2016-09-30
```

And the query that I'm trying is:

```
 SELECT A.PERIOD_DT,
   (SELECT TOP 1 CAST(B.CLASS_DT AS DATE)
    FROM TBL_B AS B
    WHERE B.CLASS_ID = A.CLASS_ID
      AND CAST(B.CLASS_DT AS DATE) <= CAST(A.PERIOD_DT AS DATE) 
      AND CAST(A.PERIOD_DT AS DATE) <= CAST(A.MAX_DT AS DATE)
    ORDER BY B.CLASS_DT DESC) AS FALLBACK_CLASS_DT
FROM TBL_A AS A
WHERE A.CLASS_ID = 358614  
ORDER BY A.PERIOD_DT DESC;
```

The result that I'm getting is:

```
PERIOD_DT   FALLBACK_CLASS_DT
-------------------------------
 2018-09-30  2018-09-30 
 2017-09-30  2017-09-30
 2016-09-30  2016-09-30  
 2015-09-30  NULL
 2014-09-30  NULL
 2013-09-30  NULL
```

Can anyone let me know how can I get this result?

Comment: Is it the result that you get from your query or is it the what you want from your query..?

Comment: Updated the expected result that I'm looking for, instead of NULL values, I'm looking for a fallback value of 2016-09-30, which is the last available value in TBL_B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query that worked for me

```
  SELECT 
    A.CLASS_ID,
    A.PERIOD_DT,
    ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 CAST(B.CLASS_DT AS DATE)
    FROM TBL_B AS B
    WHERE B.CLASS_ID = A.CLASS_ID
          AND CAST(B.CLASS_DT AS DATE) <= CAST(A.PERIOD_DT AS DATE) 
          AND CAST(A.PERIOD_DT AS DATE) <= CAST(A.MAX_DT AS DATE)
    ORDER BY B.CLASS_DT DESC
    ), B2.CLASS_DT) AS FALLBACK_CLASS_DT
FROM TBL_A AS A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT B.CLASS_ID, MIN(B.CLASS_DT) AS CLASS_DT
           FROM TBL_B AS B
           GROUP BY B.CLASS_ID) AS B2 ON B2.CLASS_ID = A.CLASS_ID
WHERE A.CLASS_ID = 358614  
ORDER BY A.PERIOD_DT DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
select a.*, coalesce(b.class_dt, bdef.class_dt)
from tbl_a a left join
     tbl_b b
     on b.CLASS_ID = a.CLASS_ID and
        b.class_dt >= a.period_dt and
        b.class_dt <= a.max_dt left join
     (select b.class_id, min(b.period_dt) as class_dt
      from tbl_b
      group by b.class_id
     ) bdef
     on bdef.class_id = a.class_id;
```

I think you can also do this using `outer apply`:

```
select a.*, b.class_dt
from tbl_a a left join
     (select top (1) b.*
      from tbl_b b
      where b.CLASS_ID = a.CLASS_ID and
            b.class_dt <= a.max_dt 
      order by b.period_dt desc
     ) b
```

Comment: either of them is not working, 1st query resulting in more rows than the 6 results that I was looking for and 2nd query is erring out. Any help please?